# How do I recreate /dev/ttyUSB## devices that I deleted?

Tags: devices

#### Background

It seems I only know enough linux to get myself in trouble.

I'm working on a couple of embedded systems (two different models) both running linux. I've been troubleshooting a modem support code that I had working with the newer one of the two. I stopped the code and tried to manually load the usbserial driver. On the newer device, when I load the usbserial driver, four devices *appear* in */dev/ttyUSB#*.

#### What I did

I noted that there were actually 16 *ttyUSB##* devices listed all the time on the older device. They never disappear. I'm guessing [now] it is because the older kernel works differently or something. **Unfortunately, I went ahead and deleted all 16 *ttyUSB##* devices**. Now they are gone and won't come back. I don't know how to create character devices. What can I do to get those devices back?

#### Kernel Version:

`uname -r` returns `2.6.17.9-ep93xx-pxa-ads5`

#### Additional Information

If there is some important piece of information I've left out, comment and I'll add it. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can manually create the /dev entry using

```
    mknod /dev/ttyUSBn c 188 n
```

- Parameters:

  - mknod is widely known tool to create /dev entries
  - /dev/ttyUSBn: device name
  - c : char device
  - 188 : major device number
  - n : minor device number,ttyUSB0, ttyUSB1, etc.

But the device should be created automatically according to the udev rules

Comment: Embedded systems don't necessarily use udev.

Answer (score 2):

Traditionally, unix systems have a script to create entries in `/dev`, called `MAKEDEV` and located in `/dev`. This script is often present on Linux, but may be absent on embedded devices where the designer assumed that all devices would be present, or on systems running udev where devices entries are normally created automatically. Note that `MAKEDEV` usually creates entries in the current directory, so run `cd /dev` first.

There's no standard for arguments that you pass to `/dev/MAKEDEV` — usually the arguments denote some set of device entries to create. On Debian, `/dev/MAKEDEV usb` creates `ttyUSB*` as well as a bunch of others. You can also look for `ttyUSB` in the `MAKEDEV` script to figure out what command line to run. The low-level command that creates device entries is [`mknod`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/mknod).

If your system uses udev, run [`udevadm trigger -s usb-serial`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/udevadm) to re-create `/dev` entries as well as run any command associated with the discovery of a device. (In this case the device is the serial port, not a device that gets plugged into the port.)

Comment: My particular system doesn't use udev and doesn't have a MAKEDEV script either. Nonetheless, this information is appreciated.